# Copy a row from one worksheet to another using a macro button

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to copy an entire row from one worksheet called "list" to the next available empty row in another worksheet called "logged".
The contents should be cleared from the original worksheet.

In this code I enter an "l" in column A of the first worksheet. I'd rather do it with one mouse click of a button:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'   Check to see only one cell updated
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
'   Check to see if entry is made in column B after row 5 and is set to "Yes"
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 4 And Target.Value = "l" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
'       Copy columns B to M to complete sheet in next available row
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "B"), Cells(Target.Row, "N")).Copy Sheets("logged").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'       Delete current row after copied
        Rows(Target.Row).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy-Clear Rows

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]
[image]

**The Code**

- When copying multiple rows, the order of the copied rows is the same as the order in the source worksheet no matter the order in which cells were selected.

```vb
Sub CopyClearRows()

    ' Constants
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "List"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As String = "B5:N5"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Logged"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then Exit Sub ' workbook not active
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    If Not sws Is ActiveSheet Then Exit Sub ' worksheet not active
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' not a range
    
    Dim surg As Range
    ' Referencing all columns, not just the columns of the used range.
    Set surg = Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, sws.UsedRange)
    If surg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' selection rows outside of used range
     
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_ROW)
        Set srg = Intersect(.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), surg.EntireRow)
    End With
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' selected cells above given first row
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    With dfCell
        ' Either, not considering cells to the left...
        Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
            dws.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        ' ... or, also considering cells to the left...
        'Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .EntireRow.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not dlCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dlCell.Row + 1, .Column)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Copy & Clear.
    srg.Copy dfCell
    srg.ClearContents ' (not considering cells to the left or right)

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Rows copy-cleared.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out when home later today.